# Test sending email in django from another thread

Tags: django, multithreading, email, django-testing

I'm trying to test my code that sends emails. More or less my unit test looks like:

```
class EmailTest(TestCase):
    def test_send_email(self):
        my_send_mail_method()
        self.assertEqual(len(mail.outbox), 1)
```

This code works perfectly fine as long as my_send_mail_method sends email in the same thread. However, when I change the code in a way that my_send_mail_method will send mail from another thread `len(mail.outbox)` is equal to 0. `my_send_mail_method` waits until the sending email is finished so I don't think it's a concurrency problem.

---

EDIT

The code that sends emails looks like assuming it's run in the same thread:

```
import timeout_decorator
from django.core import mail
from django.test import TestCase

@timeout_decorator.timeout(120, use_signals=False)
def test_send_email():
    mail.send_mail('Subject here', 'Here is the message.',
        'from@example.com', ['to@example.com'],
        fail_silently=False)
```

The thing is that my method has [timeout_decorator](https://pypi.org/project/timeout-decorator/) (there are more things going on in the method that might hang the processing and I just wanted to kill the process after some time).

I checked the code of the decorator and as far as I can tell it creates a new thread executes it, waits for response and returns it. However, I'm not very proficient in Python and might have missed something obvious here.

Comment: What is `mail.outbox`? How your `my_send_mail_method` thread waits?

Comment: show us the code that changes `mail.outbox` value and everything in between it and `my_send_mail_method`

Comment: @daniherrera I added the code that I use to send mails, sorry for leaving it out in the first place